# cor de fundo no input com o maior valor

Tags: php

Retorno uma consulta numa tabela que é montada desta forma em php:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['AvaliacaoGlobal'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['CGenericas1'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['CEspecificas1'].'</td>';
}
```

Para encontrar o valor mais alto na primeira coluna faço este if dentro do while:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

if ($maior < $teste = $rows_cursos['CGenericas1'])
   $maior = $teste = $rows_cursos['CGenericas1'];

...
}
```

Mas agora pretendo que ao encontrar o valor mais alto na primeira coluna, que coloque cor do fundo dessa célula, com o número maior a azul.

Anderson Carlos Woss, estou a tentar implementar a sua sugestão, mas ainda não consegui obter o resultado pretendido.
Depois do código para encontrar o maior valor estou a tentar comparar da seguinte forma:

```
if ($maior == $teste){
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=blue';
        }else{
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=white';
    }
```

o resultado é que está a colocar cor de fundo azul nas 3 primeiras células, onde só devia colocar cor azul na terceira que é o maior valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo:

```
$maior=0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
if ($maior < $teste = $rows_cursos['CGenericas1'])
   $maior = $teste = $rows_cursos['CGenericas1'];

    if ($maior == $rows_cursos['CGenericas1']){
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=blue';
        }else{
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=white';
    }
$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;"'.$cormaxGenericas.'>'.$rows_cursos['CGenericas1'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['CEspecificas1'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['AvaliacaoGlobal1'].'</td>';
}
```

**Solução que encontrei:**
Criei um while para encontar só o maior valor:

```
while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {
    if ($maior < $teste = $rows_cursos1['CGenericas1'])
    $maior = $teste = $rows_cursos1['CGenericas1'];
}
```

Depois criei o while onde comparo o maior valor com o valor dentro deste novo while:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

    if ($maior == $rows_cursos['CGenericas1']){
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=blue';
        }else{
        $cormaxGenericas = 'bgcolor=white';
    }
$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;"'.$cormaxGenericas.'>'.$rows_cursos['CGenericas1'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['CEspecificas1'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['AvaliacaoGlobal1'].'</td>';
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dentro do seu laço de repetição que monta a tabela, você pode comparar o valor atual com o maior valor que encontrou anteriormente. Se forem iguais, define o fundo como azul. Quer tentar?

Comment: e se houver dois ou mais valores iguais?

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo, se tiver dois valores iguais tem de colocar os dois com cor de fundo azul

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, editei a pergunta para mostrar como estou a tentar implementar a sua sugestão, mas ainda não está como pretendo

Comment: Você está encontrando o maior no mesmo laço que está exibindo?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, editei a pergunta com o código completo. Sim, estou a exibir no mesmo laço em que estou a encontrar o maior valor

Comment: Então, isso é um problema; você tem como saber qual será o maior número sem avaliar todas as amostras antes.

Comment: Para esclarecer, você precisa que em todas as colunas seja destacado o maior valor?

Comment: Sim, preciso de saber qual o maior valor nessas três colunas e colocar cor de fundo azul, para identificar o colaborador com melhor desempenho em cada uma delas

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, consegui resolver o problema, mas não sei se é a melhor prática, vou editar a pergunta com a solução que encontrei

Comment: Você não deveria publicar sua solução dentro da sua pergunta, melhor é você responder a sua própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Faça um 'for' para cada necessidade:

1) Definir índice do maior do valor

```
$indice = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($resultado_cursos); $i++) {
     if ($maior < $teste = $resultado_cursos[$i]['CGenericas1'])
           $maior = $teste = $resultado_cursos[$i]['CGenericas1'];

           $indice = $i;
     }
}
```

2) Verificar o índice:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($resultado_cursos); $i++) {
   if ($i == $indice) {
       // Com Cor

       $tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial; background-color: ' . $cor . ';">'.$resultado_cursos[$i]['AvaliacaoGlobal'].'</td>';
   } else {
      // Sem Cor

       $tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$resultado_cursos[$i]['AvaliacaoGlobal'].'</td>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Veja se agora fica mais próximo!

Answer (score 1):

SELECT max() - retorna o maior valor da coluna especificada.

Dentro do while faça a comparação com esse valor retornado

```
    $result_max = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT max(CGenericas1) AS max_page FROM AvaliacaoDesempenho");
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result_max);
    $maximo =  $rows["max_page"];

    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM AvaliacaoDesempenho");

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

        if($rows_cursos['CGenericas1']==$maximo){
            $corGenericas = 'bgcolor=blue';
        }else{
            $corGenericas = '';
        }

        $tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['AvaliacaoGlobal'].'</td>';

        $tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;"'.$corGenericas.'>'.$rows_cursos['CGenericas1'].'</td>';

        $tabela2 .= '<td style="text-align: center; font: 10pt Arial;">'.$rows_cursos['CEspecificas1'].'</td>';

    }
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica em relação ao responder a solução dentro da pergunta. A solução que encontrei não é uma boa prática? É melhor a que apresentou?

Comment: @Bruno, a resposta está data nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346459/mysql-e-php-performance-entre-while-e-select-max Caso tenha entendido me explique :-)

Comment: @Sam, to,  diga lá