# Existe diferença em encontrar o valor máximo direto no SQL ou verificá-lo com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho, memória

Eu vi em uma pergunta no site um usuário obter o valor máximo de uma determinada coluna de uma tabela no banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
$result_max = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CGenericas1 FROM AvaliacaoDesempenho");

while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {
    if ($maior < $teste = $rows_cursos1['CGenericas1'])
    $maior = $teste = $rows_cursos1['CGenericas1'];
}
```

Isto é, seleciona todos os registros da tabela, itera-os com o PHP e compara os valores até encontrar o maior.

Sei que podemos também obter o mesmo resultado diretamente pelo SQL, com a função `max()`:

```
$result_max = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT max(DCGenericas) AS max_page FROM AvaliacaoDesempenho");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result_max);
$maximo =  $rows["max_page"];
```

Qual forma seria mais performática, consome menos recursos, mais rápida etc...? Se houver, quais as razões?

Answer (score 14):

**Resposta curta**: a segunda é mais rápida e consome menos recursos, por ter menos dados para transmitir e menos processamento redundante.

---

Agora uma resposta básica para atender a necessidade do autor da pergunta e de um usuário que comentou (apagados agora pela falta de relevância com a versão atual) que desejavam uma resposta básica (apesar da pergunta pedir razões) e que minha pergunta está complexa demais:

Deixar o DB fazer o grosso do processamento é melhor que deixar o PHP tanto em memória quanto em velocidade.

> Qual forma é mais performática?

A segunda. O banco de dados processará tudo o que precisa para achar o maior e entregará uma informação única, algo bem simples e rápido de transmitir e a aplicação faz algo mínimo para pegar e usar esta informação. A outra gerará um processamento pesado no PHP, algo que já foi feito no banco de dados, fora o fato de transmitir dados demais

> Qual forma consome menos recursos?

No banco de dados o consumo é essencialmente o mesmo. No PHP a segunda forma consume muito menos recursos (imagino estar falando principalmente de memória) porque tem que lidar com uma informação, contra uma quantidade enorme de informações da primeira forma.

> Qual forma é mais rápida?

Imagino que é o mesmo que a primeira resposta, afinal performático tende nos remeter à velocidade. Se não for isso eu posso mudar se a pergunta ficar mais clara que é sobre outra coisa

> etc...

Não saberia dizer do que mais poderia estar falando, mas posso melhorar se for explicitado.

> Quais as razões?

O primeiro tem que transmitir todos os dados (todas as linhas resultantes da *query*) para o PHP poder processar, isso por si só pesa bem mais. E tem que processar todas as linhas uma vez no banco de dados e outra no PHP.

---

Agora uma resposta um pouco mais aprofundada, mas longe de ser acadêmica, para quem quer entender melhor porque isto ocorre.

Primeiro tenho que dizer que sempre é possível ser diferente por uma série de razões, e em alguns casos não fazer diferença de verdade, pense por exemplo se a tabela tiver uma linha apenas, que diferença fará? Essencialmente zero. Mas em condições normais, com grande volume de dados o processamento no banco de dados será absurdamente mais rápido, afinal na maioria dos casos **o grosso do tempo gasto é a transferência de dados** e não a consulta em si.

Em qualquer caso o banco de dados terá que ler todas as linhas da tabela para pegar os dados necessários, seja para mandar para o PHP, seja para calcular o máximo.

Calcular o máximo é ligeiramente mais lento no banco de dados porque tem um processamento extra para fazer ali. Mas a diferença é irrisória, é provável que seja bem inferior a 0,1%, já que o acesso aos dados custa bem mais. Mas isso só se considerar o trabalho no lado do banco de dados. Muda tudo quando soma-se todo o processo.

Imagine ter que transmitir milhares ou milhões de dados (linhas da tabela) para a aplicação apenas para descobrir qual é o maior. Compare com transmitir apenas o maior, uma informação única. A diferença parece brutal, certo?

E finalmente no PHP, acho que é bastante óbvio que o segundo tem um custo bem pequeno, quase desprezível para processar e de consumo de memória. O primeiro tem que processar todos os dados, então consumirá mais memória (claro que boa parte dele vai sendo reciclada em cada passo, sempre que a memória alocada não é mais necessária, então o consumo total nem é tão grande assim, mas haverá muita alocação e liberação, que em alguns casos pode ser pior para a performance da aplicação.

Para entender isso temos que buscar algo chamado [complexidade de algoritmos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101) (alerta: lá a resposta aceita é bem acadêmica, eu não aconselho segui-la para quem não tem uma base muito forte de computação, mas é ótima para um aprofundamento "matemático" da questão). O que vou falar aqui é só um verniz sobre o assunto.

É claro que todo novato não tem obrigação de saber isso, mas em determinado momento saber sobre este assunto, entre outros, claro, é o que define quem é programador profissional e o fuçador que apenas decora receitas de bolo e não consegue tomar decisões adequadas por conta própria. Dica: a maioria dos problemas de performance (alguns nem percebíveis) são por falta de entendimento básico disto (não precisa se aprofundar para usá-lo muito bem com grande benefício. E claro que todo mundo tem o direito de ignorar o assunto, por cota e risco.

Usarei a notação Big O para indicar cada complexidade (serão apenas duas). Pode entender melhor isto na excelente [resposta do Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101).

Vou falar de complexidade de tempo (execução). Não entrarei na complexidade de espaço (memória), porque na prática  não fará tanta diferença assim, a não ser na obviedade.

Tem três complexidades a serem verificados em todos este processo:

- o processamento no banco de dados
- a transmissão de dados
- o processamento da aplicação

## Processamento no banco de dados

Ambos possuem *potencialmente* uma complexidade linear (O(n)), ou seja, para cada linha existente o algoritmo terá que executar um passo. Tendo N linhas, terão N passos.

Aprendendo sobre complexidade, ela não define tempo, e um pode ser mais rápido que outro, mas a diferença não será grande. Como dito anteriormente, calcular o máximo tem um custo ligeiramente maior porque em cada passo tem uma comparação e uma atribuição de valor, mas isso é feito no momento que já está lendo os dados, e esse processamento é muito pequeno.

## Transmissão de dados

Grosso modo, o primeiro tem complexidade linear, ou seja, O(n). O segundo tem complexidade constante, portanto O(1). Então o segundo terá **um** passo não importa a quantidade de linhas que foram consultadas. É aqui que está o segredo para a diferença brutal de performance. O primeiro pode levar muitos milissegundos, ou mesmo segundos, minutos ou até horas ou dias em casos extremos, e o segundo geralmente será abaixo de 1 milissegundo. Sempre considerando só a transmissão dos dados.

Note que isso [não é tão fácil de fazer esta conta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174411/101) porque a forma de transmitir depende de uma série de questões e há algumas amortizações. De fato o que importa mais é até o espaço ocupado durante a transmissão para determinar o tempo. Se for ser preciso a conta fica complexa demais, e desnecessário para a maioria dos cenários.

Essas notações de Big O costumam trabalhar apenas com as fórmulas básicas e mais conhecidas para obter uma aproximação da complexidade real. Isso é útil para quase todos os casos que analisamos este tipo de coisa. Mas tenha em mente que a complexidade real é um O(fórmula complexa aqui).

Em resumo: se tiver 1 bilhão de linhas, a grosso modo, a primeira forma levará o tempo para transmitir todas essas linhas, e a segunda forma será um mero pacote simples. Não por conta do [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) de transmissão, não será 1 bilhão de vezes mais rápido. Se forem 10 linhas, potencialmente levará o mesmo tempo porque é provável que vá apenas em um pacote os dados das linhas ou o máximo calculado. Note que se a consulta mandar muitas colunas aí muda de figura, mas para este caso não faz sentido.

Tudo isso vale se não precisa das linhas na aplicação, só o máximo. Isso é o que a pergunta parece implicar. Se precisar das linhas para outra coisa, aí começa ficar igual. Não totalmente, mas este é outro cenário e não vou entrar em detalhes aqui.

Sempre que puder diminuir a quantidade de dados para trafegar entre o DB e a aplicação você terá algum ganho.

## Processamento da aplicação

Aqui a diferença também é brutal. Novamente a primeira é O(n) contra O(1) da segunda. É o segundo maior ponto que dará diferença, em alguns casos bem específicos e extremados pode até se tornar o principal ponto. O PHP terá um laço no primeiro, acho que isso é bem óbvio para todos como isso será mais lento que pegar o dado único do máximo, pura e simplesmente.

Nem falei que no DB a verificação rodará de forma otimizada porque foi feita em uma linguagem de alta eficiência e por um bom programador. Em PHP não tem nem perto da mesma eficiência e talvez o programador não seja tão bom assim, mas essa comparação é mais curiosa do que útil. Inclusive eu acho estranho ter atribuição em `$teste` neste código, assim a comparação fica até mais injusta, mas dá um indicação que é mais fácil ter um erro que torna ainda piro no PHP do que no banco de dados. Uma das maravilhas de um SGDB é que ele otimiza a forma de fazer a consulta, ele ajuda o programador ruim se dar melhor, ainda que ele continua exigindo certos cuidados.

## Exemplos de perguntas que mostram complexidades:

- [Como melhorar o desempenho de meu código com "for"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268296/101)
- [Como um índice melhora a performance de uma consulta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183305/101)
- [Qual a complexidade de cada uma dessas funções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122461/101)
- [Ordenar lista encadeada com método O(n*log(n))](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111198/101)
- [Análise de Complexidade de Algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72949/101)
- [Por que usar um ponteiro nesse algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255626/101)
- [Por que não se deve iterar um hashmap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268305/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1, praticamente salvou a pergunta.